# Eclipse + GAE: Properties changes and therefor problems with deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

I have had some problems with getting GAE and Maven to work with each other but that is finally solved!

I can now test my servlet locally but when I try to deploy to Google App Engine. It states that my project is not a GAE-project. When I enter the properties window and select Google -> App Engine I get a error message stating "The currently displayed page contains invalid values." I check "Use Google App Engine" and enters Application ID and Version.

When I try to deploy to GAE again I get the same message that its not a GAE-project and when I enter the properties window again I can see that the "Use Google App Engine" is unchecked.

Sometimes the checked state is saved but the Application ID is blank.

What is this error about invalid values and why are not my properties saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

As usual something really stupid...

I had a . in the version number in appengine-web.xml.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into same problem. I solved by following steps:

1) Right click on project name, open Properties
2) Select Google-> Web Application
3) Specify the WAR directory (my application is a web application so I do have a war dir)
4) Click OK

With these, i can successfully open the Google App Engine settings page without that error. The changes I made on the App Engine page can also persist

Comment: Thanks, this question may not have been useful to the original poster, but it was very useful for me.